# query for filtering published posts?

Tags: posts, query-posts, mysql, wpdb

i need to filter count based on a date and post_status = 'publish', how to write a query to filter, as far as now i have filtered based on date, what is the query need to filter based published post.

> $table1 = $wpdb->prefix.'posts'; $sql = 'SELECT   COUNT(ID) AS count
>     FROM    '.$users_table1.'   WHERE   DATE(post_date) <
>   "'.date('Y-m-d',time()).'"';       $result = $wpdb->get_var($sql);

iam stuck with this, do anyone know this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add this to the WHERE clause, just after your filter by post_date:

```
AND post_status = "publish"
```